How to prevent Javascript super constructor calling a method overridden by a derived class?
I'm new to JS and implementing a polymorphic class hierachy. It appears that within the super constructor (when called from a derived constructor), 'this' refers to the derived class, not the super class.
So, when the super constructor calls a method that the derived class has overridden, it calls the derived class version not the (original) super class version. This is not the behaviour I wanted, as it means the super constructor behaves differently for the same input parameters when it is called via the derived constructor.
A minimum working example is below:


class A {
  constructor(x) {
    console.log("A constructor");
    this.x = x;
    this.foobar();
  }

  foobar() {
    console.log("A foobar");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(x, y) {
    console.log("B constructor");
    super(x);
    this.y = y;
  }

  foobar() {
    console.log("B foobar");
  }
}

let a = new A(123);
let b = new B(123, 456);



console.log output is:
A constructor

A foobar

B constructor

A constructor

B foobar   (I would have expected this to be 'A foobar')

Have I done something wrong, and if not is there a fairly straightforward way to ensure the original (super) method is always called by the super constructor?
Many thanks in advance for any advice.
PS: I have found similar question here:
How can I prevent calling a super function from the derived class function?
The answer given is to get the super constructor to check whether the instance is of the derived type and change behaviour accordingly. This seems cumbersome, but I could go with that if no-one can suggest a better solution.

How about using a private method in the super? The convention is using an underscore prefix

When you run into problems like this, it may be an indication that you have made mistakes in designing your object system. It makes perfect sense for this in a super constructor to refer to the specific instance, because the object really is a specific instance of a specific subclass.

@mplunjan I will think about that. In my application the method needs to be public as it is also called from outside the class.

@Pointy: I'm new to JS (my background is C++) so it could be that I'm taking a C++ approach to OOP rather than a JS approach. That's something I'll learn along the way.

@TreeTownGreen you are actually using the C++ approach of Class-oriented programming, not OOP. JavaScript is an OO language that does not depend on classes. Don't confuse OOP and Class-oriented programming. The second concept is an implementation of the first one. You don't need classes in JS and you should not use them without being conscious of the issues that they bring to the language.

@EricMORLAND: Thank you, that's certainly something to think about.

In the original code, the issue was that calling this.foobar() in A's constructor invoked the foobar method of the derived class (B), if B overrode it. This happened because this in the A constructor refers to the instance being created, which is actually an instance of B.
To resolve this, you directly call A.prototype.foobar.call(this); within A's constructor instead of this.foobar(). This approach ensures that A's original foobar method is called, even if B or any other subclass overrides foobar.
So, instead of relying on this to find the method, we specifically tell JavaScript to use A's version of foobar.

Thank you, I would have accepted this as the solution but Balraj got there first!

In order to achieve the OP's expected behavior without fiddling around with constructor-function prototypes, one, for the A super class, can make use of the new.target meta-property for granting access exclusively for direct instances of A. In addition one has to implement the derived/extending class B in a way that its constructor-function directly invokes the (prototypal) A super-class' foobar method which one does achieve via the super.property expression.
The OP's changed following example code is very explicit about (thus better readable in terms of) what it intends to achieve ...


class A {

  constructor(x) {
    console.log("A constructor");

    this.x = x;

    // - answering the OP's question of how one does ...
    //   "... prevent [... the] super-constructor calling
    //    a method overridden by a derived class?"
    //
    // - allow access exclusively for direct `A`-instances.

    if (new.target === A) {

      this.foobar();
    }
  }

  foobar() {
    console.log("A foobar");
  }
}
class B extends A {

  constructor(x, y) {
    console.log("B constructor");

    super(x);
    this.y = y;

    // - exclusively invoke the `foobar`
    //   implementation of the extended
    //   class ... here class `A` ...

    super.foobar();
  }

  foobar() {
    console.log("B foobar");
  }
}
let a = new A(123);
let b = new B(123, 456);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }




Thank you for this, it's certainly a more understandable approach and one that obviously works. As a general principle I slightly prefer Balraj's solution for one reason: it doesn't require the author of B's constructor to understand the internal workings of A's constructor (i.e. that B's constructor must call super.foobar because A's constructor won't). If I could accept both answers, I would!
